# Is it better to catch run-time exception than condition judgement previously to avoid exception

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

Say, the codes below may throw run-time exception when divisor is zero.

```
try {
    int result = dividend / divisor;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("exception:" + e);
}
```

or we can write as below.

```
if (divisor != 0) {
    int result = dividend / divisor;
}
```

I am confused which one is more reasonable and why?

--------------------------------------------- update ---------------------------

I  have a new idea that if a method want to provide divide function.

```
public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) throws ArithmeticException {
    if (divisor == 0) {
         throw new ArithmeticException("divide by zero");
    }

    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

In the caller,

```
try {
    int result = divide(dividend, divisor);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("exception:" + e);
}
```

or

```
if (divisor != 0) {
    int result = divide(dividend, divisor);
}
```

Regardless of performance, both seems no problem. Isn't it?

Comment: It depends on requirement. Ideally, its advisable to delegate the exceptions to the caller (In this case an exception like `IllegalArgumentException` should be thrown from within the `if` block

Comment: This depends on where this code is. If it's the code that takes input, then maybe you should just validate the `divisor` input and not even try to calculate when it's 0. Otherwise I wouldn't catch the exception and would let the JVM raise it for whoever is responsible for validating input to deal with the runtime exception. But this is a matter of opinions.

Answer (score 2):

**Definitely use conditionals when you can!**

Throwing and catching exceptions is very slow, much slower than checking whether some number is equal to 0. The same goes for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (checking whether the index is greater than 0 and less than length of array), `NullPointerException` (check if the object is null), `NumberFormatException` (check if a string is in the correct format before calling things like `Integer.parseInt`).

Error handling is not for flow control. When you use `try...catch`, you are handling something you really can't control. Many methods have checked exceptions, and those are the exceptions you should catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `if` condition then `if (divisor != 0)` is reasonable but imagine multiple divisions where their value may change at run time then so many `if-else` is headache and exception(may be your custom) is better approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: one advantage of exception is separating ugly "Error Handling" codes from "Regular" codes. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html

Comment: @Saint Where does my answer negate this statement?? Is this the reason for downvote??

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what do you mean totally in the comment. I didn't do anything include down vote. The answers from you and Sweeper both are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The second code block is the better when dealing with math calculations.